# Customize the django form widgets

Tags: css, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

forms.py

```
INCIDENT_LOCATIONS = (
    ('01. Classroom', '01. Classroom'),
    ('02. Corridor', '02. Corridor'),
    ('03. Stairs', '03. Stairs'),
    ('04. Playground', '04. Playground'),
    ('05. Sportsground', '05. Sportsground'),
    ('06. Excursion', '06. Excursion'),
)

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    keywordsearch=forms.CharField(max_length=100,label="search")
    incident=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'special'}))
    location=forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    fromdate = forms.DateField(label="From Date", input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'], validators=[validate_date])
    todate = forms.DateField(label="To Date", input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'], validators=[validate_date])
```

1.How to write css class to increase the length of the particular field ,I required incident field to be more length than keywordsearch field

2.How to create drop down box in django.Main purpose of this is to select any one of the  above option.Here to select the incident location in location field i am trying to do.I don't know how to display this form in the html page.

3.How to reduce the length of date field in form,as it is taking equal length like normal text box.

Please help me to proceed the above.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.How to write css class to increase the length of the particular field ,I required incident field to be more length than keywordsearch field

You can use the `size` attribute,

```
incident=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'special', 'size': '40'}))
```

2.How to create drop down box in django.Main purpose of this is to select any one of the above option.Here to select the incident location in location field i am trying to do.I don't know how to display this form in the html page.

Instead of using CharField, use `ChoiceFIeld`,

```
location=forms.ChoiceField(choices=INCIDENT_LOCATIONS)
```

3.How to reduce the length of date field in form,as it is taking equal length like normal text box.

The default form widget for this field is a TextInput. So like in number one you can use the size attribute.

Comment: how to display the choice field form in the template

Comment: just call `{{form.as_p}}` in your template. Where is you view codes so that I can teach how?

Comment: views.py not yet written,just i initialized a search function in view and concentrated on html design

Comment: Catherine,if you have documents about signals concept in django please share.I am not make me clear from Django doc

Comment: yeah I've been thinking of posting signal in my blog but I can't find a subject. If you like you can request on me, just tell what do you want me to do in signal

Comment: To know more about Signals like application area,how to apply so on

Comment: Ok I will post that maybe in Saturday or Sunday, my free time

Comment: where i can find that post

Comment: in my blog. there is a search engine at the top, type signal and enter

Answer (score 1):

Write your own css classes:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs

```
>>> name = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 10, 'title': 'Your name',})
>>> name.render('name', 'A name')
u'<input title="Your name" type="text" name="name" value="A name" size="10" />'
```

For create dropdown box you can use:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#selectmultiple

```
location=forms.CharField(max_length=100 widget=form.SelectMultiple)
```

And for reduce length you can use another css class like:

```
.myclass { width:100px; }
```